# MySQL Select Date Equal to Today in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have below code to get the customers whose term is ending today.

```
$customers = CompanyModel::where(("term_ending") ,"=", "CURDATE()")->get();
```

But when I run this it returns null.

Same query I run in Mysql it gives me results.

```
select * from `companies` where `term_ending` = CURDATE()
```

What is wrong I am doing?

Comment: This probably depends on how CompanyModel is defined. Please include some more code.

Comment: If you want to use mysql native functions you have to wrap that in \DB::raw()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using Carbon.

$customers = CompanyModel::where(("term_ending") ,"=", Carbon::today())->get();

Thanks :)